# NodeJS Express HTTP POST Multiple files upload in one request vs Multiple requests (ONE Request ONE File) for performance

Tags: node.js, express, http-post

I am using NodeJS, express, and MULTER to upload files to the server. I may select one or more files to upload from my Angular APP and I am thinking to go with Multiple HTTP POST request(ONE Request ONE File) as the uploading of files may be happening parallelly (ExpressJS backend) and track each file upload status.

If I use One HTTP POST Request for all the files, I am assuming the response time will be high as it has to process all the files before issuing a response. I can code accordingly to improve the response time however confused with the approach to proceed.

Each file size may be less than 75 MB. Any thoughts on this scenario, in terms of performance and memory efficiency about choosing between ONE HTTP POST Request for all files vs MULTIPLE REQUEST (ONE Request ONE File).

I understand that there are PROS and CONS in both approaches and it would be ideal to go with what fits my requirement. I am trying to understand the factors that decide the suitable approach.

Answer (score 0):

For me it depends to how many is "multiple" and how big is the average size.

But it is safer to go with "multiple but quick sessions" than 1 big long session on the backend/server side.